# Add portions of string that contains X to list

Tags: python, string, search, append

I'm trying to learn Python and I have one question.

I want to take all html links from a webpage source file and append them to a list. For example I want to search the string for every instance of ../lyrics.*html and insert those instances in a list. The result would be a list of html links such as this:

```
["../lyrics/steviewonder/lovesinneedoflovetoday.html", "../lyrics/steviewonder/haveatalkwithgod.html", "../lyrics/steviewonder/villageghettoland.html"]
```

Help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: How are you getting the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to search for such strings.

```
import re

re.match(r"(.*)/lyrics/(.+?)html", line)
```